# Read configuration file with js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, configuration, get

I was wondering how to read a conf file with HEX colors in it using js/jQuery? I guess I will have to do it with an Ajax GET request. And how do I solve the cross domain” / ”same origin” security problem in an appropriate manner that I will encounter?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the conf file? What cross domain problem are you going to encounter?

Comment: On another server. I was refering to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: your question didn't make it clear where you are trying to get the file from. The local computer, the same server hosting the calling page, another server on the same domain, or a server on a completely different domain. How you solve security problems will vary based on where you are trying to get the file from.

Comment: Your right. Im trying to acces the conf file from my local computer and it is located on another domain. Hence via http. So Im not sure the "right" way to go about it. With jsonp or some other way. Do you have any good suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two options: somehow return proper CORS headers, or request the file using the server rather than jQuery.

Edit: That is, if it really is a cross-domain request.

Comment: Yes it is a cross-domain request. Ok so then I have to create a XMLHTTPREQUEST object?!

Comment: ? i dont understand what you are asking.. I guess yes? Making an ajax request does create an XMLHTTPREQUEST object, but you can let jQuery do that for you.